# How to write gotoif (i > -2 && i < 100) in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I tried the following method, but unfortunately it did not work.

```
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${lnn}&gt;-2 &amp;&amp; ${lnn}&lt;100</td>
    <td>label111</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
store  |  10  |  i
gotoIf | storedVars['i'] > -2 && storedVars['i'] <100  |  true
getEval| alert("Condition Fails")
gotolabel | finish
label  |  true
getEval  | alert("Condition Pass")
label  | finish
```

You can pass any value for i.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code and let me know if still you are getting same error message ?

```
- Created one JScript file ith following content.

var searchValue=new Array("-1","-2","500","300","20","100","12");


store | 0 | looptimes
while | storedVars.looptimes <= 6   
storeEval | searchValue[storedVars.looptimes] | search
open | http://www.google.co.in/     
waitForText | id=gbqfba | Google Search
waitForText | id=hplogo | India
gotoIf | storedVars['search'] > -2 && storedVars['search'] <100 | labelforthis
getEval | alert("Value is not greater than -2 and less than 100.")  
label | labelforthis
type | id=gbqfq | ${search}
click | id=gbqfb    
store | javascript{storedVars.looptimes++;}     
endWhile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gotoIf | storedVars['search'] > -2 && storedVars['search'] <100 | labelforthis
```

can be replaced by

```
gotoIf | -2 < storedVars['search'] <100 | labelforthis
```