# How to use loops in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Is for loop present in Selenium IDE? if yes, How can I use it in Selenium IDE?

Thanks,
Nit

Answer (score 2):

We can use while loop and goto function in Selenium IDE.

For that we must install the addon flow control. Add from the following link:

[Selenium IDE: Flow Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flow-control/)

After installing you will get the commands while and gotoif in Selenium IDE

**1) Example for  `while` loop**

```
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>index = 0;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>index &lt; 10;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>index</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>index++;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

**2) Example for `gotoif`**

```
store  |  10  |  x

gotoIf | storedVars['x'] > -2 && storedVars['x'] <50  |  true

getEval| alert("Condition Fails")

gotolabel | finish

label  |  true

getEval  | alert("Condition Pass")

label  | finish


try this Thank you..
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can have looping in IDE
You can refer below URL for looping in IDE

[Selenium IDE: How to Pass Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588508/selenium-ide-how-to-pass-variables)
[How to write gotoif (i > -2 && i < 100) in Selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413653/how-to-write-gotoif-i-2-i100-in-selenium-ide/11415085#11415085)
http://radical-qa.blogspot.in/2012/02/selenium-ide_09.html