# how to execute automated steps 10,000 times in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have the recorded steps to create user in selenium. same user insertion does not matter. but essential is to execute single recording 10,000 times. is it possible in Selenium addons itself or do i need to write the code using Selenium API's.

Comment: first Add the addon Selenium flow control , then you requirement can be executed using while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to program anything. This can be done even in Selenium IDE (guess you are using it now) with recording just one case.

See these resources to help you:

- [How to use loops in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585392/selenium-ide-and-what-all-loops-can-be-used)'
- [How to use user extension in Selenium IDE (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbN92y7JMxM)
- [Sideflow user extension](https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow) (used for while loops in IDE)