# Selenium IDE "[error] Threw an exception: illegal character" error while using storeEval command

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am writing following test case:

```
COMMAND               TARGET                         VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------
storeXpathCount      *someXpath*                     totalRows
store                3                               i
while                ${i}<=${totalRows}
storeText            *someXpath*                     MyVersion
storeEval            storedVars['MyVersion']=='103'  result
gotoIf               ${result}==false                lebelForIf
label                labelForIf
storeEval            {i}+1                           i
endWhile
```

I am getting error at the line where i have storeEval  storedVars[..]
The error is "[error] Threw an exception: illegal character".

Basically i want to search a version ( i.e. 103) from column which has "totalrows" thus iterating using i, wherever the version matches I want to take some action.

If the above snippet is not proper is there any other way to write this code in Selenium IDE?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the while loops are supported in Selenium IDE directly. We have to install user extensions for this.
Refer to the following link for more info - [How to use loops in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585392/selenium-ide-and-what-all-loops-can-be-used)

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.However i have already included the looping feature by using goto_sel_ide.js.Please check http://www.computerminds.co.uk/automating-boring-tasks-selenium-ide

Comment: no :( ...Thats why i had posted it here.Anyways I think i will use WebDriver for the coding.Still If i can get an answer for the above mentioned questions it will  be great.